# Insertion of number sign (#) into a Google Spreadsheet via GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have encountered a problem when trying to insert a "#" sign into a cell using script (that is triggered to run when a submission comes from a form).

I have tried to do it this way:

```
somecell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("http://www.some.link/some/'+var+'#1a2b3c","'+var+'")');
```

So the output should be:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.some.link/some/1234#1a2b3c","1234")
```

But it is always inserted as only (no # and the rest of link after the sign)

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.some.link/some/1234","1234")
```

There are no errors reported during execution.
How should I put the sign into the script so it will be inserted into the formula? I had tried using ...1234(backslash)#1a... but it does not work.

**Edit**
How does the script work (in short): firstly, sheet receives a form submission with an URL as one of the entries. Then, the script cuts off part of the link (using *.split('/')* and then *.pop()* to get the last element of the array that *.split* created) and the variable extracted this was is used in the *.setFormula* seen above as *var*.

Also, I have tried again; backslash does not work - everything after (and including) # is deleted.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the reported problem behaves as expected, and is not actually the source of the error experienced by the author.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a backslash to escape the character:

```
function addlink() {
  var somecell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('F2');
  var blah = "123";
  somecell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("http://www.some.link/some/'+blah+'\#1a2b3c","'+blah+'")');
  //                                                                ^^^
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I wanted to state that I had tried to use backslash in the question post, the backslash was deleted; the last sentence for the question post should look like this: "I had tried using ...1234(backslash here)#1a... but it does not work." I will edit it right away.

Also, I will edit the post above with some clues that might suggest you the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example like this :

```
function test(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var xx = '1234'
  sh.getRange('A2').setFormula('=HYPERLINK("http://www.some.link/some/'+xx+'#1a2b3c","'+xx+'")');
}
```

and I get the expected result

[image]

Comment: I have found the reason for this situation, the function that was called (and contained this problematic line of code) was copied twice in the script (and onyl the second instance was running - the one without recent changes) and that was my fault that I had not found this out since beginning.

Well, sorry for making a problem from nothing, this post can(or should) go to a trash bin.

My apologies again!